# How to efficiently filter and collect to a resulting map with differently derived map values from a few maps?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

I have a few `Map` objects that are keyed by the same type `K` with differently typed values `V1...VN`, which for the purpose of this question do not share a supertype*:

```
Map<K, V1> kv1
Map<K, V2> kv2
Map<K, V3> kv3
...
Map<K, VN> kvN
```

I need to create a resulting map of type `Map<K, V>`, by filtering each of these maps differently, and then use a 'value mapper' to map the `V1...VN` values to a commonly-typed `V` new values (i.e. a `Function<? super Entry<K, VN>, ? extends V>`) on these maps. As such, I have the following `static` helper method to perform the first two steps:

```
public static <K, VN, V> Map<K, V> filterAndMapValue(final Map<K, VN> map,
        final Predicate<? super Entry<K, VN>> predicate,
        final Function<? super Entry<K, VN>, ? extends V> mapper) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().filter(predicate)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, mapper));
}
```

My current use cases make it safe to assume that *only after* the filtering on each map will give me distinct keys for the final `Map` object (there can be the same keys used in each map), but in the event that does not hold true in the future, I know I can provide a supplementary `mergeFunction` expression to `Collectors.toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)` to handle this properly.

The final code now reads something like the following:

```
Map<K,V> result = filterAndMapValue(kv1, predicateForKV1, mapV1toV);
result.putAll(filterAndMapValue(kv2, predicateForKV2, mapV2toV));
result.putAll(filterAndMapValue(kv2, predicateForKV3, mapV3toV));
...
result.putAll(filterAndMapValue(kvN, predicateForKVN, mapVNtoV));
// do something with result
```

**Question:** Is there a more efficient way of doing this? This sounds like yet another case of reducing stuff (filtered maps) into a final collection (`Map`) which requires different reduction invocations (the value mapping part), and I am not sure if I am approaching this the correct way or not.

* - If they do, then I guess `V1...VN` can implement a parent method, say `V convertToV(Object... possiblyAdditionalArgumentsToPerformTheConversion)`, so that my problem is reduced to just applying different forms of filtering for different maps. If there is also a simpler solution *given this alternate assumption*, feel free to mention it too.

Comment: How about creating an object to hold all V1...VN values, and use only one map?

Comment: @BobTheBuilder do you mean to collect all the maps' values at the start? The value mapping is done differently for different types, and then at the end I also need to know the keys' mappings for the newly created `V` values... I've also provided an edit to indicate that the 'unique resulting keys' is only applicable *after* the filtering on the maps, so the original maps can have the same keys. I wouldn't be able to do a `Map<K, Object>` in that sense. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: What I mean is to create a class MyValues which has V1..VN fields. If you use that class, MyValues holds all the values for each key in one object and it is easier to handle and maintain

Comment: @BobTheBuilder do you mind putting that as an answer? I'm sorry, but I still don't think it fits my case here as it is crucial that my processing is filtering the maps differently, and then applying a different mapping function from `V1...VN` types to `V`. Perhaps a fleshed-out answer can correct any misunderstanding I have regarding your approach here? :)

Comment: Hmmm not sure if it can be combined more than what you did, because as you said, the values have no common type so combining them in one statement would result in unsafe/ugly cast somewhere I guess. One thing though, you could maybe make `filterAndMapValue` return a `Stream<Entry<K,V>>` and then you concat all the Streams with `Stream.concat` and you collect them in a single map there (with a merge operator if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your method to

```
public static <K, VN, V> Stream<Entry<K, V>> filterAndMapValue(Map<K, VN> map,
    Predicate<? super Entry<K, VN>> predicate,
    Function<? super Entry<K, VN>, ? extends V> mapper) {

    return map.entrySet().stream().filter(predicate)
              .map(e->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), mapper.apply(e)));
}
```

you can perform the operation as a single `Stream` operation like:

```
Stream.of(filterAndMapValue(kv1, predicateForKV1, mapV1toV),
          filterAndMapValue(kv2, predicateForKV2, mapV2toV),
          filterAndMapValue(kv3, predicateForKV3, mapV3toV),
          …)
      .flatMap(Function.identity())
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Note that for a small number of input maps, you may use `Stream.concat` but as the number grows, the approach shown above is preferable.

I wouldn’t expect a noticeable performance gain, but this approach will verify your assumption that there are no duplicate keys in the remaining entries.